# Maven build Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have problem after build project on maven in jar.

I make package and create .jar file:

```
mvn package
```

after i run my jar file

```
java -jar artifactId.jar
```

and get error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.emercit.app.App
```

If i run class in target directory, i get similar error:

```
cd target/classes/com/emercit/app
java App
Error: Could not find or load main class App
```

My code in App class:

```
package com.emercit.app;

public class App extends Application {

   /**

     Program code

  **/

    }

public static void main (String[] args) {


    //Init form
   Thread myThready = new Thread(() -> {
        launch(args);
    });
    myThready.start();

    }
 }
```

My build properties in pom.xml:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.emercit.app.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/lib
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: could you share github link?

Comment: Isn't your main() outside of the class?

Comment: https://github.com/sterkhov/BuildError

Comment: App contain main(), and in IDEA project it work

Comment: You shouldn't run `App` in `target/classes/com/emercit/app` from console, you run `com.emercit.app.App` from `target/classes`.

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class App` means that the class App were not found - are you sure that maven even generates the classfiles for you? Have you placed the App-class under the correct project structure? Meaning `/src/main/com/../../App`? If not, you'll might have to add a `<resources/>`-configuration.

Comment: No matter. I get Error: Could not find or load main class com.emercit.app.App

Comment: @Sterkhov dont forget the fact that this still is java cmdline application. With that being said, you lack buildmanifest.mf file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: @Reborn How i can add this property?

Comment: @Sterkhov you need to make new file called as Manifest.mf and specify there your path to main class. Since, it is maven project 1) make manifest.mf file with args 2)mvn package 3) make jar as mentioned here wikihow.com/Create-JAR-File (step 3 already includes manifest creation) This is not 100% working

Comment: `<addClasspath>false</addClasspath>` should be set to true otherwise your .jar won't be able to find the dependencies copied by the maven-dependency-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Build your jar with this plugin and specify the main class, this will add the correct META-INF in your generated jar.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>com.barclaycard.blackboxtester.Application</Main-Class>
                                        <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is similar to how I do it except you need to change this parameter in your POM file to be a value of "true".

```
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```

Without it you would have to include dependencies on the command line and you are not.  Java won't find jars just because they are in a directory.  This command will add a "classpath" in the MANIFEST.MF file withing the JAR.

The generated MANIFEST.MF file would contain a line something like this (taken from one of my opensource projects).  Your jar dependencies would of course be different.

```
Class-Path: calendar-2.2.3.jar algebrain-2.2.3.jar commons-codec-1.9.j
 ar argument-4.3.8.jar slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar l
 og4j-1.2.17.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The file structure while creating any mavenized project should **src/main/java** and package should be include in class file 
other wise it will throw error Could not find or load main class